# How To Toggle Android Camera Flash On Microphone Audio Capture?

Tags: android, camera, microphone, flashlight, blink

The following code works. It makes the camera flash to blink on any audio captured by the Android phone microphone. It works on Samsung Galaxy S Duos. 
All I want is to make it more stable because of the presence of the thread.

```java
package net.superlinux.concertlights;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

/**
* @author راني فايز أحمد
* 
*/
public class FlashOnMicrophone extends Activity {

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
 // Toggle button that switches Camera-flash-to-blink on and off. 
ToggleButton flash_on_microphone_toggleButton;
//SeekBar to set the microphone sensitivity level at which the flash will blink.
SeekBar seekBar;
//Camera Object
Camera camera;
/* Preparing a Thread to make the GUI seperate from Camera and Microphone.
Otherwise the phone will hang and freeze. */
Thread thread;
 //mRecoder is the microphone object
MediaRecorder mRecorder;
 //A flag used in the thread to turn on the flash blinking .  
 boolean isLightOn = false;
//sensitivity holds the minimum amplitude value at which the camera flash will blink
int sensitivity=0;

   @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setContentView(R.layout.flash_on_microphone);
   flash_on_microphone_toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.flash_on_microphone_button);
    seekBar=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
   //SeekBar of sensitivity default is 1500. 
    seekBar.setProgress(1500); //default sensitivity value

       //The following event listener sets the global variable 'sensitivity' so it can be taken by the thread.
  seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   //There is a TextView not mentioned in the code here, but it's in the XML layout.
   //We use this TextView to display the variable sensitivity
   //We also set the current position of the SeekBar button as the sensitivity.
            sensitivity=progress;
               ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.microphone_sensitivity_textview)).setText(getString(R.string.microphone_sensitivity_level)+"= "+sensitivity);

        }
    });


    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
          //The following makes sure that a camera exists. else warn the app user and quit the app.
    if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Device has no camera!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }

      //Display has to be always unlocked to keep the flash light working.
  getWindow().addFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

     //Open the Camera, and get its parameters to set the camera settings.
    camera = Camera.open();
    final Parameters p = camera.getParameters();

      //We open a thread , but will  run it after defining the microphone.

    thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
       //we make the thread running for ever.
      // every time isLightOn is true , we blink the flash light.
     // and turn on the flash light if the microphone amplitude exceeds the value of the variable 'sensitivity'
            while(true){
            while (isLightOn) {
                try {

                   int volume_level = mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();

                    if (volume_level>sensitivity){
                Log.i("info", "torch is turn off!");
         // make the flash off and the camera preview off too.
        //we cannot reach the flash light device without the camera preview. both are attached to the other

                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                camera.setParameters(p);
                camera.stopPreview();
         //now make  the flash on and the camera preview on too.
                    Log.i("info", "torch is turn on!");
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                camera.setParameters(p);
                camera.startPreview();
          //The camera preview will not work in this case because the on & off on the preview pameter is very fast
                    }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.i("info", "torch is turn off!");

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
            }
        }
    });
         /*
          Prepare the audio capture source to be the microphone.
          and save the audio in the file "/dev/null" .
          This is a special file in Linux. Please know that Android is a Linux distribution.
          This file acts like black hole in the space. You may also think of it as the dumpster of the unwanted and exiled data.
          We, here , do not want to save the sound. All what we want is to sense it, and nothing else. so we throw it away in "/dev/null" .
          */

     mRecorder= new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder. setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP); 
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB); 
    mRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null");
    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //now turn on the microphone and the thread.
    mRecorder.start();
    thread.start();

    //the event of turning on/off the flash-on-microphone sensing
    flash_on_microphone_toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

     //flip isLightOn between true and false.
            isLightOn = !isLightOn;

        }

    });


}
        @Override
      public void onBackPressed() {

     //clean up and activity shutdown.
     mRecorder.stop();
     thread.interrupt();
    super.onBackPressed();
      }
      @Override
      protected void onRestart() {

     //re-run the camera on application minimize and maximize.
 camera=Camera.open();
 super.onRestart();
      }

     }
```

Comment: might be a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be about reviewing working code, which would be better suited on [codereview.se].